# Como verificar o status Code de uma requisição ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um requisição AJAX bastante simples. Mas gostaria de saber se tem como ler o *status code* retornado dentro do método `done`. Mais ou menos como abaixo:

```js
$('#form-aluno').submit(() => {
    let data = $('#form-aluno').serialize();


    const register = $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "/alunos/register/save",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data
    })

    register.done((e) => {
        console.log(e.statusCode) //tem como fazer algo do tipo ou similar ?
    })


    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema em questão. Vou deixar a resposta aqui caso alguem tenha mesma duvida

resolvi utilizando o terceiro parametro callback da função done do ajax conforme abaixo:

```
register.done((e, status, code) => {
    console.log(code.status)
})
```

Comment: Ajax implementa so XMLHttpRequest. Veja aqui para usar isso de forma simple e ler os codigos. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp